# How to make transistor operate in active or saturation-and-cutoff region

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, analog

There are plenty of quotes on the internet like this one:

> "There is nothing like 'analog transistor' and 'digital transistor'. A
> transistor is a transistor! Simple. One can make either analog
> circuits or digital circuits out it by making the transistor operate
> in either linear (active) region or between on-and-off
> (saturation-and-cutoff) regions respectively. "

Can transistors be changed from operating in active vs saturation-and-cutoff region, after they have been manufactured, and sold. Or, is this mode of operation something that has to be built into the transistor, by balancing N and P regions and whatnot. (If the latter, it sure does seem to me it must be reasonable to refer to things as "active" or "saturation-and-cutoff" transistors, or, with a synonym, analog and digital. But it seems to upset many, so I ask if these modes can be switched between easily after transistors reach market. )

Comment: You can set the operating region with base current (BJTs) / gate voltage (FETs). Regarding manufacturing process, some transistor are more suitable for switching (saturation point) some for amplification (active region)(good linearity).

Comment: The mode of operation is set by the circuit around the transistor, not anything to do with the manufacturing process. That's what the quote you quoted is trying to say: the circuitry determines how the transistor acts.

Comment: @Michael P., the operating region is NOT set with base current. Rather, it is set by base voltage (both, the B-E and the B-C junction must be forward biased). In this case, the large base current is an INDICATION for saturation only (not its cause).

Comment: Neither. Every transistor (be it bipolar or FET) can operate either way. Take an active region transistor amp and overdrive its input hard enough : it now alternates between saturated and off. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Hearth I understand what the quote means, if transistors in general, incl. in a analog components like diff amp and op amp, reach saturation at 0.7 volt. And something to step down voltage or current is needed to use inputs above 0.7v. But that seems kind of inefficient to me. Not how I would expect it would be organized, so I asked.

Comment: That's *sort of* how it works, but Vbe is still 0.6~0.7 volts (for a silicon BJT only, it's different if we're talking about different semiconductors) when the transistor is in forward active mode. At this level, it's easier to think of the transistor as being controlled by the *current* into the base, not the voltage, since the voltage is almost constant in both forward-active and saturation mode. If you get down in the weeds of device physics, it is true that the voltage-controlled model fits better, but stick to currents if you're new to electrical engineering.

Comment: I wasn't talking about voltage or current, I specified they can be controlled by both to avoid an unnecessary lecture. My original question is if the extremely small voltage that turns transistors on in digital circuits (passing linear region etc), is also going to be the limit of transistors in analog circuits. It seems very counter-intuitive that it would be the case. If it is, what is the main way to step down voltage when I input multiple volts into an op amp?

Comment: I was feeding multiple volt into a 741 op amp input the other day. In schematics, there is no resistor before the base. And I did not use one. But it was reacting in proportion if voltage was adjusted. My assumption is that if base is max on at 0.7 volt, I do not understand how going above that will cause proportional response in the "diff amp" unit that the inputs go to. I might miss something in overall circuitry, that effect is elsewhere. Or, the transistor gate I used might have different response curve than max at 0.7volt (what I think seemed most plausible. )

Answer (score 2):

That quote is not wrong, but that doesn't mean there aren't transistors specifically designed for a particular application, switching or linear. It is true that *any* transistor can be operated in *any* of the three regions, saturation, cut-off or active/linear, but some transistors are better for switching applications than others.

In a switching application your concern is mainly with the time it takes for a transistor to transit from saturation, through the active region, into cut-off, or vice versa. All transistors can make that transition, but some transistors do it more quickly.

In a linear application, such as an audio amplifier, you never really drive transistors into saturation, or completely into cut-off, and this transition time is of little consequence. You may be more concerned with the linearity of the transistor in its active region, where it spends 100% of its time.

Transistors can't recover instantly from saturation, because it takes time for charge carriers in the base region to vacate, and return the transistor to linear operation, or cut-off. The amount of time it takes for such recovery is a function of junction geometry and doping, and where recovery time is critical you could choose a transistor with better recovery time than others, but you could also mitigate recovery delay by simply designing the circuit in such a way that the transistor is never driven deeply into saturation.

Similarly, if the base-emitter junction is reverse biased, and the transistor is deeply into cut-off, it takes time to repopulate the base-emitter depletion region with charge, and restore it to an active-region state. Again, the solution could be to use a transistor designed to recover from this condition quickly, or simply ensure that the base-emitter junction potential difference is never permitted to become negative, or even approach zero.

So, while there are transistors designed with fast recovery in mind, for switching applications, all of them have the same saturation/active/cut-off states, and they all suffer from the same recovery issues.

In all cases it is a transistor's periphery, those components responsible for biasing and source/load impedance, which are defining whether the transistor is a switch or a linear device, not the transistor itself.

Here are some articles showing the transistor in two different configurations, with wildy differing bahviour, hopefully helping to show why it's not the transistor itself which is deciding its role, so much as the components around it:

[Common-emitter (allaboutcircuits.com)](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/common-emitter-amplifier/)

[Common-emitter (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter)

[Common-collector (allaboutcircuits.com)](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/common-collector-amplifier/)

[Common-collector (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector)

These principles also apply to field-effect transistors (where they would be called "common drain" or "common source"). In common-collector configurations, the transistor is always operating in its active/linear region, but the common emitter approach is more suited to switching.

Comment: My main concern is, in a diff amp that can take inputs of many volt, and I see no circuitry in schematic that reduces voltage, and digital circuits usually apply 0.7 volt to transistor base to reach saturation, it seems they must use transistors designed and manufactured for different input voltage ranges. Would you say that isn’t the case?

Comment: @Doge It's not the voltage referenced to ground that matters, that can be anything it wants to be. It's the voltage between the base and the emitter that matters. You'll notice that a diff amp never has the emitter grounded; there's a current source there instead. This adjusts the emitter voltage so that Vbe stays in its normal range of 0.6~0.7 volts.

Comment: @Hearth if 1) transistors and response curve is the same and 2) only circuitry differs and 3) what you wrote there is true, I really want to understand it. Because if I understand diff amp, it opens up a lot (basis of so much else. ) But I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Hearth with not grounded, you mean there is resistor in between it and ground? Like they show here, https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/transistor-emitter-ground.135230/#post-1130126. I can get that, but don't get why that makes arbitrary max volt input at base (say, 0.7x10 = 7 volt) act as 0.7 volt.

Comment: the resistor between emitter and "ground" decreases the base emitter current. right. but why that is contradictory is because people often emphasize transistors being voltage gated. I then assume current gated would be mostly used for those types of analog circuits? or can that stuff (voltage/current gates) be just ignored and it still explains it?

Comment: @Hearth Like you wrote, "You'll notice that a diff amp never has the emitter grounded; there's a current source there instead." Thanks. Yes, I think I am starting to get it.

Comment: @Doge Remember that it's the voltage *between the base and emitter* that matters here. The base can be at 10,000 volts without any problems, *as long as the emitter is at 9999.3 volts*.

Comment: @Doge That's what the resistor (or current source, more commonly and more effectively) on the emitter does for the transistor; it makes the emitter have a positive voltage with respect to ground, so that the base voltage can be whatever it wants to be, with the emitter voltage following it.

Comment: @Hearth yeah I think I managed to get what I missed thanks to you. But thanks for more comments. I will think about them a bit.

Comment: @Heart You've already helped me a long way on this. That it is the difference that matters, is good that you point out. And, that the resistor after the emitter preserves the voltage, no voltage drop, I understand that. Could you expand a bit on the last part, "the emitter voltage following it"? It seems like it might be what I need.

Comment: @Heart I am testing it in Falstad simulator now, with the Differential amplifier template. If I increase input A with 100mV, the voltage at wire below emitter moves closer to it with 100 mV. This seems to be exactly what I was wondering about. I was imagining something like it (but very different because I am a beginner), that a change must happen somewhere else when increasing input voltage.

Comment: @Hearth I think I will find that I have it answered with that. But have to think about it a while. Thank you a lot, it would have been really hard for me to figure that out on my own. And understanding the diff pair seemed like a good stepping stone or exercise.

Comment: @Hearth Increasing base voltage and conductance through transistor, will reduce resistance in transistor and voltage drop over it, which increases voltage after it. Brilliant. It would have taken me forever to figure that out. Extremely basic knowledge probably but as a beginner I could not see that intuitively.

Comment: @Doge take a look at the articles I've added (linked) to in my answer., about common-emitter and common-collector configurations. With common-emitter, the emitter is tied directly to some power supply rail, and since base potential cannot ever deviate further than 0.7V from its emitter potential (say, ground, 0V), the base is also constrained. By contrast, if you put something between emitter and that rail, like a resistor or current source (like common-collector), the emitter is free to rise and fall in potential, and consequently the base also is no longer constrained.

Comment: Simon I already got the answer from Hearth. It was explained and communicated well. You must be able to see that from the exchanges. So yes I understand putting resistor between emitter and ground is the key. This was what I was missing, and thanks to @Hearth response to me here on your answer, I got it. Appreciate effort from you both that contributed to it, helps a lot, would not have figured it out myself very easily. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

Using a transistor in an analog or digital mode is an application of the transistor. It can fulfill either application to varying degrees depending on its architecture. Read something basic such as [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/transistors/operation-modes).

[image]

The architecture of transistor will set the performance of the device for any given application. For example RF transistors are quite different to small signal and power transistors as they are optimized for RF applications. This is why there are many types of transistor, they are purpose designed.
For example transistors that are used in applications requiring low VCE(sat) are designed to provide the lowest possible VCE(sat). Here's an OnSemi power device, the [NSS40500UW3T2G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nss40500uw3-d.pdf#:%7E:text=PNP%20Transistor%20ON%20Semiconductor%E2%80%99s%20e2PowerEdge%20family%20of%20low,switching%20applicationswhere%20affordable%20efficient%20energy%20control%20is%20important.), they don't explain the architecture of the transistor, but clearly the VCE(sat) is extremely low at currents up to 4A.

Comment: I understand transistors can fullfil both _depending on their architecture_. You should be able to read that in from the question. What it asks is if the optimization for different modes is something that is done after fabrication, or during. And in the latter case, it must be possible to understand that calling a transistor ”digital-optimized”or ”analog optimized” or optimized for whatever, is not unreasonable at all.

Comment: @Doge, that's exactly what I said. Transistors are optimized for particular applications, but in general they all have flexible operation in any of modes you describe.

Comment: That they can all work in either saturation-and-cutoff or active mode, is self-evident. Bu that they would do this over different voltage ranges, and this is optimized at fabrication, was more what I was asking about. Most answers or comments seem to imply "no, transistors used in analogue and digital circuits have the same voltage range" and if that is true then ok. It seemed contradictory to me, because it seemed efficient to be able to use gate with more than 0.7 volt saturation, but I am a beginner so might be true.